# Accessing camera - Delay to close the uiactionview when clicked on the cancel button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When we try to access the camera, we get a `UIActionView`, where it will say if you want to access the camera, or the album, or cancel.

My code works perfectly but when i click on the cancel button, it takes like 30 seconds to cancel. And i have not written any code inside the cancel method. I simply left it empty.

Why is this delay ? and how can i prevent it ?

code

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {


        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]; 

    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {


        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

    } else {



    } 

}
```

Comment: Going to need a bit more code to understand what's going on because this is not typical behavior clearly

Comment: I am using UIactionsheet in my code. But there is no delay for me when I tap the cancel button. I don't know why there is a delay for you. I will check my code and let you know.

Comment: Yes please, i haven't added any code to the cancel button. I have no clue why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this code connected up to Xcode (i.e. it is running in the debugger) then you will be getting a pause as it tries to allocate the UIImagePickerController. This is very slow in the debugger. Try running not plugged in and it should be faster, Also try not to init it unless you need it.

It might seem bad to repeat the code but you can probably help this by putting:

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
```

inside the if statement.

Hope this helps :)

Try this:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]; 
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    } else {
        // Cancel button code here
    }
}
```

This does it a slightly different way

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex != actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex) {
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]; 
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    }
} else {
    // Cancel button code goes here
}
```

}

So we first check that it's not the cancel button, if not we create the UIImagePickerController, then use it in the two cases where it is required. If it i the cancel button then it just does nothing.

That should look a bit happier.

Comment: Then , i will also have to put it inside the `if else` statement as well ?

Comment: Also are you aware that in your example you are leaking the UIImagePickerController. Unless of course your using ARC??

Comment: Yes you'll have to put it in where I have in the sample. But you won't put it in the else at the end, where you know that you will not need the UIImagePickerController. It should solve the problem.

Comment: What might be the exact reason for you to alloc/init  `UIImagePickerController` to both if and if-else ?

Comment: Well in both of those code paths you will need your UIImagePickerController. The way you had it before meant when you pressed any of the buttons you were creating one, when you don;t always need to. Give me 2 mins and i'll add another code snippet that may be preferable.

Comment: The second sample I have posted does it a more logical way :)

Answer (score 0):

I had what sounds like this exact problem. Which I solved by changing the way I presented the ActionSheet.

I changed from this:

```
[actionSheetMedia showInView:self.view];
```

to this:

```
[actionSheetMedia showInView:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

Now the lag and unresponsive Cancel button are no more.